# How to store last insert id in codeigniter session if insert is donr by AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I need to insert last insert id of user on some event .....
And I want to get that on another page....
Like On product page ....user customizing his product....like [mug customization](http://www.zazzle.com/registered_nurse_symbol_coffee_mugs-168057801348371344)

And i need to get the inserted....customization product id to the cart page and this is done by ajax....so how can i get last insert id on cart page from product page....

### my ajax...

```
$('#store').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_url_store,
        data: {
            action: 'store',
            views: JSON.stringify(thsirtDesigner.getProduct())
        },

        success: function (data) {

            if (parseInt(data) > 0) {
                //successfully added

                document.getElementById('succes-message').innerHTML = 'You Design has Been SuccessFully Saved';
            } else {

            }

        },
        error: function () {
            //alert('some error has occured...');
        },
        start: function () {
            //alert('ajax has been started...');    
        }
    });
});
```

My ci function

```
public function saveData() {

    if ($this - > input - > post('action') == 'store') {

        $views = $this - > input - > post('views');
        $id = $this - > product_model - > save($views);

        if ($id != '') {
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function saveData() 
{

  if ($this->input->post('action') == 'store') 
  {

    $views = $this->input->post('views');
    $id = $this->product_model->save($views);
    $data = array('userid'=>$id);       //insert id to userid as session variable
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);  //set userid as a session variable

    if ($id != '') 
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($id);
    }
  }
}
```